# Securely store auth key for PHP sessions on Redis

Tags: php, security, redis, phpredis

Let's say a site is using redis (remotely) to store session data, and that redis store is protected by an auth key

So in php.ini, using phpredis, it's set to something like:

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://redis.example.com:6379?auth=[AUTH_STRING_HERE]"
```

Is there any way to make this a little bit more secure? Anyone on the server who then runs phpinfo(); can see the auth string...

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 7, you can pass an array of options to the session_start() command, e.g.

```
session_start([
    'save_handler' => 'redis', 
    'save_path' => 'tcp://redis.example.com:6379?auth='. $your_auth
]);
```

That way, you can use the standard 12-factor app best practices of storing sensitive data in a .env file.

For versions of php prior to 7, you should be able to use [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) to override values stored in your php.ini file(s).

Comment: Note that despite setting your `save_path` when starting the sessions, the save path (and `auth` password) will still be accessible via `phpinfo()`, `session_save_path()` and `ini_get()` after starting the session. You can, however, change the save path to an empty string after starting the session so it cannot be seen anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this path via php code using ini_set method. And in the code pick the value from a file/string which can store this as an encrypted string.

Answer (score 0):

disable phpinfo, also try setting up an external script or file command which sends the auth string (it's less security and more obfuscation, but it will move the problem further down the line)